# How to get a content of a aws s3 object?

Tags: java, unit-testing, amazon-s3, junit, assertion

I wrote a java code for reading an AWS S3 file content if it is a text file and the unit test for testing. 
Here, in unit my test, I create a temporary file in a temporary folder, write the content to the file and upload it to the s3 file `(@BeforeAll)`. The following utility class is for reading that uploaded file.

I hope the method I wrote does its job. But the unit test I wrote fails due to an Assertion error.

The following are my utility class and the unit test. 
Can someone point out where I had it wrong?

**Utility class**

```
public static S3Response read(S3Request s3Request) {
        S3Validation.source(s3Request);
        S3Object s3object = AWSClient.getAwsS3Client().getObject(S3RequestBuilder.read(s3Request));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s3object.getObjectContent()));
        String line;
        try {
            line = reader.readLine();

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while (line != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            String fileAsString = stringBuilder.toString();
            response.setResponse(fileAsString);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            LOGGER.error(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return response;
    }
```

**JUnit test**

```
 @Test
    public void test_readFile() throws IOException {
        s3Request = new S3Request();

        s3Request.setSourceURI(CommonParameters.S3_PREFIX + SSMUtil.getBucketName(SSMParameters.SSM_BUCKETNAME)
                + "/ReadFile/read.txt");
        S3Utils.read(s3Request);
        System.out.println(S3Utils.read(s3Request).getResponse());
        assertEquals(content, S3Utils.read(s3Request).getResponse().toString());
    }
```

And I used the following method to write the content to the file.

```
 Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(uploadReadSource));
        File read = File.createTempFile("read", ".txt", new File(uploadReadSource));
        s3Request.setLocalPath(read.getAbsolutePath());
        s3Request.setDestURI(CommonParameters.S3_PREFIX + SSMUtil.getBucketName(SSMParameters.SSM_BUCKETNAME)
                + "/ReadFile/read.txt");
        BufferedWriter bufferWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(read));

        bufferWriter.write(content);
        bufferWriter.close();
        S3Utils.uploadFile(s3Request);
```

**S3Response Class**

```
public class S3Response {
    private boolean isSuccess;
    private String response;

    public S3Response() {
    }

    public S3Response(boolean isSuccess, String response) {
        this.setSuccess(isSuccess);
        this.setResponse(response);
    }

    public boolean isSuccess() {
        return isSuccess;
    }

    public void setSuccess(boolean isSuccess) {
        this.isSuccess = isSuccess;
    }

    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse(String response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

 }
```

The Assertion error I am getting is;

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <This is the temporary data written to temp file> but was: <This is the temporary data written to temp file
>
```